# Spring RestTemplate Copy property HttpHeader to RequestBody

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

Our application is calling other rest service using RestTemplate, its a Spring Boot application. I have some requirement where I need to copy property from http header to request body.

Doing it manually would lead to changes at many places. I am looking for a generic solution ie, I could extend the functionality of RestTemplate and use it across the application.

Is there any way to modify RestTemplate in order to achieve my requirement. I have already gone through possibilities through HttpMessageConverter, I am able to append Json Property but looking for a way where it could be copied from Header.

Please let me know if I am not clear with my requirements, any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend RestTemplate behaviour by implementing [ClientHttpRequestInterceptor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/ClientHttpRequestInterceptor.html)

```
public class RestTemplateHeaderModifierInterceptor
  implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {

    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(
      HttpRequest request, 
      byte[] body, 
      ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {

        ClientHttpResponse response = execution.execute(request, body);
        response.getHeaders().add("Foo", "bar");
        return response;
    }
}

@Configuration
public class RestClientConfig {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors
          = restTemplate.getInterceptors();
        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(interceptors)) {
            interceptors = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        interceptors.add(new RestTemplateHeaderModifierInterceptor());
        restTemplate.setInterceptors(interceptors);
        return restTemplate;
    }
}
```

[Reference](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-interceptor)